# Qt instantly rotate animation

Tags: c++, qt, animation

I know this may be a stupid question but I really can't seem to find an answer anywhere. I created a triangle like this:

```
    QPolygonF triangle;

    triangle.append(QPointF(0., -15));
    triangle.append(QPointF(30., 0));
    triangle.append(QPointF(0., 15));
    triangle.append(QPointF(15., 0));
```

This triangle shall represent a car on my map, and I need to animate it. So i did the following:

```
    QGraphicsItemAnimation *animation;
    QGraphicsPolygonItem *clientCar;
    QTimeLine *timer;

    animation = new QGraphicsItemAnimation;

    timer = new QTimeLine(10000);
    timer->setFrameRange(0, 100);

    clientCar = scene->addPolygon(triangle, myPen, myBrush)

    animation->setItem(clientCar);
    animation->setTimeLine(10000);

    animation->setPosAt(0.f / 200.f, map.street1);
    animation->setRotationAt(10.f / 200.f, 90.f);
    animation->setPosAt(10.f / 200.f, map.street2);
    animation->setRotationAt(20.f / 200.f, 180.f);
    animation->setPosAt(20.f / 200.f, map.street3);

    scene->addItem(clientCar);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    timer->start();
```

The problem is, when it reaches an intersection(road cross) it should rotate so that it will face the road it's going next. As you can see above, I tried using setRotationAt(), but what it does is slowly rotating between intersections until it reaches the next one. It should be turning in an instant, only when it's changing it's way. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc:

> **QGraphicsItemAnimation** will do a simple linear interpolation between
>   the nearest adjacent scheduled changes to calculate the matrix. For
>   instance, if you set the position of an item at values 0.0 and 1.0,
>   the animation will show the item moving in a straight line between
>   these positions. The same is true for scaling and rotation.

The *linear interpolation part* will do the trick.
So why don't you try this:

```
//animation->setPosAt(0.f / 200.f, map.street1);
//animation->setRotationAt(10.f / 200.f, 90.f);
//animation->setPosAt(10.f / 200.f, map.street2);
//animation->setRotationAt(20.f / 200.f, 180.f);
//animation->setPosAt(20.f / 200.f, map.street3);

static float const eps = 1.f / 200.f;
QVector<float> steps = {0.f, 10.f / 200.f, 20.f / 200.f};
QVector<QPointF> points = {map.street1, map.street2, map.street3};
QVector<float> angles = {0, 90.f, 180.f};

// initial conditions
animation->setPosAt(steps[0], points[0]);
animation->setRotationAt(steps[0], angles[0]);

// for each intersection
for(size_t inters = 1; inters < points.size(); ++inters)
{
    animation->setRotationAt(steps[inters] - eps, angles[inters - 1]);
    animation->setPosAt(steps[inters], points[inters]);
    animation->setRotationAt(steps[inters] + eps, angles[inters]);
}
```

Comment: @R.Andrei Please accept my answer if you don't mind ;)